# Facebook Marketing API: Is it possible to filter insights by status

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am trying to filter adsets insights by adset status, but when I add a status filter, I get an empty dataset back:

```
curl "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/act_<redacted>/insights?fields=clicks,impressions,cpc,ctr,account_id&time_range%5Bsince%5D=2016-01-12&time_range%5Buntil%5D=2016-09-12&access_token=<redacted>&format=json&filtering=%5B%7B%22field%22:%22status%22,%22operator%22:%22EQUAL%22,%22value%22:%22ACTIVE%22%7D%5D&level=adset"
```

here is what filtering param looks like before it gets url-encoded:
`[{"field":"status","operator":"EQUAL","value":"ACTIVE"}]`

I have tried all valid values for status `ACTIVE, PAUSED, DELETED, ARCHIVED` to no avail.
When I remove filtering param - I see my data.

The question is:
Does anyone know if it is possible to filter by status, and if it is, what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible. Using latest version as of March 2018.

You need to actually request all the ads that are ACTIVE and then provide `insights` as a 'nested' list of fields.

Replace 123456 with your ad account (but leave the `'act_'` which is needed)

> act_123456/ads?fields=effective_status,name,insights{total_action_value,total_actions,actions},adset_id,campaign_id&filtering=[{'field':'effective_status','operator':'IN','value':['ACTIVE']}]

This also works for `/campaigns` and `/adsets`

---

You can also do this (be sure to include `&level=ad`):

> act_123456/insights?fields=ad_id,adset_id,campaign_name,action_values,campaign_id,total_action_value&level=ad&filtering=[{"field":"campaign.delivery_info","operator":"IN","value":["active"]}]

Comment: Remember that active status, and delivery info status are as of the time you make the call.

Comment: dude you saved my night <3

Comment: @LaylaZhang happy to hear :) one thing I should add is to remember these statuses are based on the *current* status of the campaign. So if you filter by ‘active’ for last week but the campaign was since stopped then it won’t be in the results.

Comment: When I search the PHP SDK, for `delivery_info`, I see no results. I *can* see in the SDK: `\FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AbstractArchivableCrudObjectFields::EFFECTIVE_STATUS`. When I search https://www.google.com/search?q=site:https://developers.facebook.com+delivery_info&source=lnt&tbs=li:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijnpb6itTkAhULlawKHVpXAIsQpwUIKQ&biw=1920&bih=947, the only doc I can find is https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/best-practices/storing_adobjects/ which hasn't helped me learn why my queries aren't working.

Answer (score 0):

i m using this to filter campaigns with insights , working for me , start playing with it

```
'filtering'=>
                  array(
                        array(
                        "field"=>"campaign.effective_status",
                        "operator"=>"IN",
                        "value"=>$campaigncheckstatus,
                      ),
                  ), 
$campaigncheckstatus =  array("ACTIVE","PAUSED");
```

dont forget to json_encode $campaigncheckstatus if passed through url

Comment: I was very encouraged by your answer but couldn't get it to work in v2.7 or 2.8. Do you know how to do it in 2.8? Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584176/retrieve-facebook-insights-for-all-active-ads-within-an-account Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Filtering by insights isn't possible. At least in v2.7. To get insights for let's say ads I've decided to do the following:
1. Fetch ads that I need via `/ads` call. This allows me to filter by status.
2. Fetch insights for the same collection of ads and make sure that I ad id is included in the response.
3. Filter the second collection using the first one.

Comment: Hi Ilya, I bet you know how to answer this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42584176/retrieve-facebook-insights-for-all-active-ads-within-an-account (Your summary here wasn't detailed enough for me to figure it out.)