# Retrieve Facebook Insights for all active ads within an account?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

My code allows me to retrieve all ads that between certain dates, but this includes ads that are no longer active.

I want to show insights only for ACTIVE ads. **How can I retrieve Facebook Insights for all *active* ads within an account?**

```
public function getInsights($levelType, $id, $aggLevel, $start, $end) {
    if ($levelType) {
        if ($id == null) {
            abort(400, 'You must provide the ID for the object you want to retrieve.');
        }
    } else {
        $levelType = \AdAccount::class;
        $id = ACT_PREPEND . $this->fbConfig['account_id'];
        $aggLevel = AdsInsightsLevelValues::CAMPAIGN;
    }
    $variableClassWithNamespace = '\FacebookAds\Object\\' . $levelType; //TODO: avoid hard-coding class paths as strings
    $level = new $variableClassWithNamespace($id);
    $fields = [
        InsightsFields::SPEND,
        InsightsFields::CAMPAIGN_ID,
        InsightsFields::CAMPAIGN_NAME,
        InsightsFields::ADSET_ID,
        InsightsFields::ADSET_NAME,
        InsightsFields::AD_ID,
        InsightsFields::AD_NAME,
        InsightsFields::UNIQUE_IMPRESSIONS,
        InsightsFields::INLINE_LINK_CLICKS,
        InsightsFields::INLINE_LINK_CLICK_CTR,
        InsightsFields::COST_PER_INLINE_LINK_CLICK,
        InsightsFields::ACTIONS,
        InsightsFields::COST_PER_ACTION_TYPE,
        InsightsFields::CPM,
    ];
    $params = [
        AdReportRunFields::LEVEL => $aggLevel,
    ];
    if ($start) {
        $params[AdReportRunFields::TIME_RANGE]['since'] = $start;
        if (!$end) {
            $params[AdReportRunFields::TIME_RANGE]['until'] = (new \DateTime("+2 year"))->format('Y-m-d');
        }
    }
    if ($end) {
        $params[AdReportRunFields::TIME_RANGE]['until'] = $end;
        if (!$start) {
            $params[AdReportRunFields::TIME_RANGE]['since'] = (new \DateTime("-1 year"))->format('Y-m-d');
        }
    }
    if (!$start && !$end) {
        $params[AdReportRunFields::DATE_PRESET] = InsightsPresets::LIFETIME;
    }
    $insights = $level->getInsights($fields, $params);
    return $insights->getResponse()->getBody();
}
```

I'm using the Facebook PHP Ads SDK 2.8 (`"facebook/php-ads-sdk": "2.8.*"` in `composer.json`). The [documentation is here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/v2.8).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use filtering on delivery_info to Active. It would be looks like the following in your http request

```
filtering:[{"field":"campaign.delivery_info","operator":"IN","value":["active"]}]
```

Please refer to the filtering section in the document.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/insights/parameters/v2.8

```
filtering
list<Filter Object>
Default value: Array
Filters on the report data. This parameter is an array of filter objects.
field
string
Required
operator
enum {EQUAL, NOT_EQUAL, GREATER_THAN, GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL, LESS_THAN, LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL, IN_RANGE, NOT_IN_RANGE, CONTAIN, NOT_CONTAIN, IN, NOT_IN, STARTS_WITH, ANY, ALL, AFTER, BEFORE, NONE}
Required
value
string
```

If you want to see the code, please check this filtering field in the PHP SDK. It's just mirroring the actual API fields

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk/blob/53bee21251a9d898591708b96d1afa9e13516e3d/src/FacebookAds/Object/Campaign.php#L220

Also, we recently launched a scenario based codegen wizard tool. You can walk through the "Create Ad Report" wizard, and it will generate code for you. (Although it only support Java for now)

The URL of the tool is: (replace your own app ID)
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/your_app_id/marketing-api/quickstart/

Comment: I'd love to accept your answer as correct, but I have been unable to find documentation about `filtering` or `delivery_info`. E.g. none of the results of https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:developers.facebook.com+delivery_info&* specify how that would work.  Can you please send a link or a more specific working example of a `->getInsights()` call that uses a filter?

Comment: @Ryan, I edited my answer, I hope that gives you some context.

Comment: The top of that page says "This document refers to a feature that was removed after Marketing API v2.7." Maybe this feature isn't supported anymore. I'll accept your answer anyway because I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @Ryan, Facebook just release a tool call Facebook Ads Manager for Excel. It allows you to download reports right into Excel 2016. You may want to play with it: https://www.facebook.com/business/m/facebook-ads-manager-for-excel

Also, you may try Getting Started tool in https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[app_id]/marketing-api/. It allows you to run through a wizard and generate a java code for getting insights.

Comment: this returns nothing for me now :-(

Answer (score 0):

This works, you are actually requesting all the ads that are ACTIVE and then providing `insights` as a 'nested' list of fields.

Replace 123456 with your ad account (but leave the `'act_'` which is needed)

> act_123456/ads?fields=effective_status,name,insights{total_action_value,total_actions,actions},adset_id,campaign_id&filtering=[{'field':'effective_status','operator':'IN','value':['ACTIVE']}]

This also works for `/campaigns` and `/adsets`

This is the only way I figured out how to do it. I couldn't get any filtering to work for `/act_123456/insights` at the root level.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone not being able to get the filtering to work for /act_123456/insights, when you are using 'level' = 'ad' you need to have the following filtering:

```
{'field':'ad.effective_status','operator':'IN','value':['ACTIVE', 'PAUSED', 'DELETED', 'ARCHIVED']}
```

Now it does apply the filtering for me!